# Famo.us: Implementing History API for navigation

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to rebuild a basic app in Famo.us (including it's magic of course). The problem I have is while creating the navigation. Every guide I've seen it only updates the content of the same Surface. In famo.us you can create a navigation but I think it would get very difficult to keep track of the history as the HTML5 history API does. Also the "back" button of Phonegap implement this functionality so it's something we should consider. At last, not less the Angular/Famo.us doesn't include a Router. So my question is, How should we be implementing a navigation system using Famo.us?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need (well... need...) to use hashbangs for this, or at least, that's how I'm doing it. You're basically using window.location.hash to do the navigation and editing this (even in a browser), does not trigger a page reload but just sends an event to notify the app that the hash has changed, and then you can let the app act on it. Changing the hash also adds a history element, so window.history can be used to navigate to the previous (or next) page(s)!

This is also (sort-of) the way www.famo.us does it:
http://www.famo.us/university/lessons/#/famous-101/displaying/4